# App имеет очень большой размер при наличии dsym файла

Tags: c++

Использую следующие флаги:

```
    set_target_properties(${proj_name} PROPERTIES 
        XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS "YES")

    set_target_properties(${proj_name} PROPERTIES 
        XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "dwarf-with-dsym")

    set_target_properties(${proj_name} PROPERTIES 
        XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_COPY_PHASE_STRIP "NO")

    set_target_properties(${proj_name} PROPERTIES
        XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING "YES")
```

На выходе получаю большой `dsym` файл (порядка `200Мб` ) и слишком большой для меня `ipa` файл (`estimate size 60мб`, без символов всего `30мб`).

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Отдавайте пользователям release-версию. Там, соответственно, не будет dsym-файла (или будет, но маленький, не помню)

Comment: Нужен нормальный dsym, для того чтобы креши разбирать.
В данный момент, у меня есть креш, но нет символьной информации чтобы его читать.

Comment: А разве нельзя dsym хранить у себя? Да, пользователи будут присылать креши без адресов, но потом у себя можно будет восстановить. Но есть ещё чудесное средство - логи.

Comment: C dsym файлов полный порядок, проблема в "слишком большой для меня ipa файл (estimate size 60мб, без символов всего 30мб)."

Comment: А ipa-файл разве не из-за dsym разрастается?

Comment: Михаил, что вы имеете в виду? не очень вас понял.

Comment: Что сборщик ipa помимо exe'шника засовывает в ipa ещё и веcь dsym (очевидно, сжатый)

Comment: Если разархивировать ipa файл, то в нем нет следов dsym.

Comment: A, значит моя догадка была неверна. Поставьте там моему ответу пару минусов